# How can I get proper response back from scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some search results from this company register, but when i try to scrape the company name my results dont seem to return properly, its like the company name item is split into 2 html items based of the search keyword.

Is there a way to join these together? This is my spider

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'gov2'
start_urls = ['https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=a']

def parse(self, response):

for i in response.css('ul.results-list'):
  yield {
      'company_name': i.css('li.type-company h3 a::text').extract(),
      'address': i.css('li.type-company p::text').extract(),
  }
```

My results as you can see its missing some parts.. [image]

Hope any of you see whats going on.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you want to fetch all the texts within `a` and `p` tags and there is many `tags` within this tags.

Try this one and remove the unnecessary spaces through `regex`:

```
import scrapy
import re

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'gov2'
    start_urls = ['https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=a']

    def parse(self, response):

      for i in response.css('ul.results-list'):
         yield {
          'company_name': re.sub('\s+',' ',''.join(i.css('li.type-company h3 a ::text').extract())),
          'address': re.sub('\s+',' ',''.join(i.css('li.type-company p ::text').extract())),
      }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I was looking for! Ill look some more into regex! thats amazing haha!

Answer (score 1):

Using the regex, just modified the code for a better output.

```
import re
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'gov2'
  start_urls = ['https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=a']

    def parse(self, response):
      for i in response.css('.type-company'):
        yield {
            'company_name': re.sub('\s+', ' ', ''.join(i.css('h3 a ::text').extract())),
            'address': re.sub('\s+', ' ', ''.join(i.css('p ::text').extract())),
        }
```

Comment: Thanks the output looks way betetr hahah